# ios: large number of database records - possible?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I may need to process a large number of database records, stored locally on an iPad, using Swift. I've yet to choose the database (but likely sqlite unless suggestions point to other). The records could number up to 700,000 and would need to be processed by way of adding up totals, working out percentages etc.

Is this even possible on an iPad with limited processing power? Is there a software storage limit? Is the iPad up to processing such large amounts of data on the fly?

Another option may be to split the data into smaller chunks or around 30,000 records and work with that. Even then I am not sure its a practical thing to attempt.

Any advice on how, or if, to approach this and what limitations may apply?

Comment: Try it. Worry about optimizations only once you detect an actual issue.

Comment: I would try CoreData, optimized for high data traffic https://www.google.com/search?q=core%20data%20performance&rct=j

Comment: Yeah, give core data a try. I used it with a few hundred thousand items and millions of relationships. That was 5 years ago and it ran fine.

Comment: That gives me some hope, will take a look, thanks. Will also need to automate a way of getting the very large csv file(s) into a relational sqlite db, possibly via mssql..any suggestions welcome..will create another question.